# Probability of two players getting the same opponents two matches in a row

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, binomial-coefficients

> There are $8$ players in a game in which each player is paired up with another for each match (so $4$ pairs per game). Label these $8$ players $A$ - $H$. What is the probability that player $A$ gets paired with player $C$, AND player $B$ gets paired with player $D$, both pairs for the $1st$ game, and then this exact pairing occurs again with game $2$?

So for the first game, the probability of player $A$ getting player $C$ is $\frac{1}{7}$, and same with player $B$ and $D$. But since all the pairings occur at the same time, I'm not sure how to change this probability. Since we cannot match players to themselves, it seems like it depends on who is paired with who first. For example, if a player is paired first, they have a lesser probability of obtaining a specific oponent. The last two players to get paired of course will always get each other. So how do we compensate for the random pairing orders?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2173818/the-number-of-ways-to-pair-2n-players-in-a-tennis-tournament)

Comment: Well, conditioned on the pair $A,C$ the probability of pair $B,D$ is $\frac 15$, by the same reasoning you used to get $\frac 17$.

Answer (score 0):

First: I'm assuming that choices for the second game are independent of the choices for the first game and have the same distribution?  That being the case, 
$$
\begin{align*}
P(AC,BD\text{ in games 1 and 2})&=P(AC,BD\text{ in game 1})\cdot P(AC,BD\text{ in game 2})\\
&=[P(AC,BD\text{ in a game})]^2.
\end{align*}
$$

Now, how to compute this probability? One way to think of this is that you want to find the total number of ways that all pairings can be constructed, and the total number of those pairings that satisfy the condition you've specified.

The total number of pairings is $7\cdot 5\cdot 3\cdot 1$.  Why?  First, we choose an opponent for player $A$. This can be done in $7$ ways.  Now, find the player with the lowest letter that hasn't been assigned, and choose their partner; that partner can't be $A$, $A$'s partner, or the one we're trying to match; but, any of the remaining $5$ choices is valid.  Etc.

Now, how many such arrangements match $A$ with $C$ and $B$ with $D$?  We can form such an arrangement by choosing matchings for $E$, $F$, $G$, and $H$; like before, this can be done in $3\cdot 1$ ways (choose a partner for $E$ in three ways; then, pair the two remaining together.)

So, overall,
$$
P(AC,BD\text{ in a game})=\frac{3\cdot 1}{7\cdot 5\cdot 3\cdot 1}=\frac{1}{35},
$$
and therefore
$$
P(AC,BD\text{ in games 1 and 2})=\frac{1}{35^2}.
$$