# How many different games in a tournament of $2^n$ players

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I am interested in the following question: suppose we have $2^n$ team to play tournament and there are two teams paired play in each round until we have one team (winner) left. There are some rules in the game:

1. The order of the pair does not matter, e.g. $(team A, team B)$ is equivalent to $(team B, team A)$
2. We only randomly pair teams in the first round. After the first round, each "adjacent" winners play. For example, if the first round paring is $(AB, CD, EF, GH)$ and suppose the winner is $(A, C, E, G)$, then in the next round, $A$ will play with $C$ and $E$ will play with $G$.
3. We can assume who wins the game are deterministic, or in other words who wins will only depend on the true ability of the team.

The question is how many different games are there. This question is similar to some existing one e.g. [The number of ways to pair 2n players in a tennis tournament](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2173818/the-number-of-ways-to-pair-2n-players-in-a-tennis-tournament).

Some of my thoughts so far. 1. As after the first round, the game structure will be fixed. So we only have to think about how many different games can we have in the first round. 2. As the first step, we can think about how many different ways to pair teams. For example, we have $\frac{2^n!}{2^{n-1}!4^{n-1}}$ ways. However, it seems hard to proceed to get the final answer.

Comment: Do you mean "how many different brackets up to isomorphism"? Because there are always $2^n-1$ games needed to decide the winner!

Comment: that's correct!

Answer (score 1):

There are $(2^n)!$ ways to arrange all teams in the first round. Each of the $2^n-1$ games divides this number by two, since swapping the sub-brackets leading up to this game produces an isomorphic bracket. Since these are the only isomorphisms, the final answer is $(2^n)!/2^{2^n-1}$ – [OEIS A067667](https://oeis.org/A067667), "the number of knockout tournament seedings".